# existe alguna forma de hacer que una venta se abra afuera de un iframe en html?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo el siguiente codigo html en una pagina que llamaremos pagina1.html

```
`<div onclick="DetalleAviso()">
<label>Anuncio1<label></div> 
</div>`
<script> 
function DetalleAviso(){  
window.open("aqui va la url" , "blank") 
</script>
```

ahora , tengo una segunda pagina html que llamaremos pagina2.html
la cual consume mediante un iframe la pagina1.html de esta manera sera a groso modo pero quiero que la idea quede en claro

```
<iframe src="pagina1.html"></iframe>
```

la cuestion es la siguiente , como podemos observar en la pagina1.html al dar click a ese contenedor nos abre una nueva pestaña en la cual navegara a una url indicada eso lo logramos mediante el atributo "_blank" pero ocurre la situacion de que la pagina2.html al consumir pagina1.html la url se abre en el mismo iframe y yo busco evitar que eso suceda como puedo lograr evitar que la url se abra en el mismo iframe y se abra en una pestaña diferente en pagina2.html?

Comment: Te falta una llave y tus divs no coinciden pero supongo que eso es sólo un error de copy-paste; como se ve tu código debería funcionar como esperas, podrías intentar replicar el problema en el editor de código de acá?

Comment: tienes razon , no puse bien la etiqueta de cierre del div , esto solo es un ejemplo sencillo , solo quiero que la idea quede clara , claro mi codigo original es muy diferente a este , el problema en si es que como pagina2.html consume mediante el iframe pagina1.html no quiero que se abra la url en el iframe si no mas bien en una nueva pestaña

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, es posible hacer que una venta se abra fuera de un iframe en HTML. Puedes lograrlo utilizando la función window.top.open() en lugar de window.open() en tu código. Esto asegurará que la nueva ventana se abra en la parte superior (fuera) del iframe, en lugar de dentro del mismo.

Aquí tienes una versión modificada de tu código:

```
<div onclick="DetalleAviso()">
  <label>Anuncio1</label>
</div>

<script>
function DetalleAviso() {
  window.top.open("aqui va la url", "_blank");
}
</script>
```

Al utilizar window.top.open(), estás accediendo al objeto window principal de la página que contiene el iframe en lugar de la ventana interna del iframe. Esto garantiza que la nueva ventana se abra en la pestaña principal de la página pagina2.html, en lugar de dentro del iframe.

Espero que esto te ayude a lograr el resultado deseado.

Comment: gracias me sirvio de ayuda tu respuesta , espero que esto también le sirva a alguien mas que lo necesite :)